# Accessing a web application running in Ubuntu from other machines in the same network

Tags: networking, tcp, ubuntu-22.04

I have an application running in Ubuntu 22 that deploys a web server at port 8000 and it's accessible through the browser at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (from the same machine).
I would like to access this URL from other machines in the network so I tried using the IP address http://192.168.1.21:8000 (rather than the localhost one; 127.0.0.1) and I checked the port 8000 is opened in the firewall... But so far, I can't access this website from outside the Ubuntu machine...
I'm wondering if I need something else to configure in Ubuntu to make this work. In windows, you can access any webserver running at localhost using the machine's IP address (assuming the port is opened in the firewall), but it seems this is not the case in Ubuntu? Note that I don't have a webserver such as Apache installed and running, but the application itself deploys a webserver so I assume this is not needed.

Thanks in advance
Gus